# Path exists in expressjs but says POST 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, express, post, routes, controller

So I am stuck on a very basic route error.

**Project Structure:**

```
- controllers
   authentication.js
- routes
   auth.js
   pages.js
- views
   register.html
- server.js
```

**Respective codes**

controllers/authentication.js

```
//...
exports.register = upload.none(), function (req, res) {
  //...
}
//...
```

routes/auth.js

```
const express = require('express');
const authController = require("../controllers/authentication");
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/register', authController.register);
module.exports = router;
```

routes/pages.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register');
});
module.exports = router;
```

views/register.html

```
//...
<form action="/auth/register" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
/...
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const { dirname } = require('path');
const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, './public');
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use('/', require('./routes/pages'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port http://localhost:8080');
});
```

When I submit the form the console says
`POST http://localhost:8080/auth/register 404 (Not Found)`.

But if I skip the `controllers/authentication.js` part and define every thing from `exports.register` in `routes/auth.js` in `router.post('/register', ....);` it works just fine.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing `register` middleware in an array, now it's exporting only `upload`:

```
//...
exports.register = [upload.none(), function (req, res) {
  //...
}];
//...
```

or you could move `upload` middleware to the `register` middleware and call it from there:

```
const upload = multer().none();

exports.register = (req, res, next) => {

     upload(req, res, (err) => {
        //...
     }
};
```

Comment: Placing as an array did solve the problem. Thanks!